# Write tcpdump output to compressed / gziped file

Tags: bash, debian, gzip, tcpdump

I want to write the textual output of `tcpdump` to a compressed file.

First I tried the most obvious:

```
# tcpdump -l -i eth0 | gzip -c > test.gz
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C63 packets captured
244 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
4 packets dropped by interface

# file test.gz
test.gz: empty
#
```

Then I found the following solution for `Debian 9 (Stretch)`:

```
# tcpdump -l -i eth0 | ( gzip -c > test.gz & )
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
^C150 packets captured
160 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel

# file test.gz 
test.gz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Wed May 23 12:56:16 2018, from Unix
#
```

This works fine on `Debian 9 (Stretch)` but not on `Debian 8 (Jessie)`:

```
# tcpdump -l -i eth0 | ( gzip -c > test.gz & )
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
tcpdump: Unable to write output: Broken pipe
#
```

Two questions:

1. What's wrong with the 'obvious solution'?
2. How to capture and zip the tcpdump output in Debian Jessie? (The obvious solution doesn't work there either)

Thanks!

Comment: The obvious solution would have worked with enough content flowing through the pipeline. If you're only trying to capture a few lines, or need to capture everything up to the very end when ctrl+c is pressed, then... yeah, you've got the issue here. (However, capturing only very small amounts of content is not *usually* the kind of case when in-line gzip is needed).

Comment: BTW, for extra paranoia, you could change the `tcpdump`s in my answer to `stdbuf -oL tcpdump`, to tell glibc to flush tcpdump's output after every line. Shouldn't be needed, though, since SIGINT is capturable (and so allows the program an opportunity to do a final flush itself). You'd need it if shutdown were happening with SIGKILL, however.

Comment: ...btw, [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) may be useful supplemental reading.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I ve just verified it. `gzip` writes only to file, when a full 32k block is compressed. Since my original `tcpdump` output contained many similar lines, it would have taken quite long until the 32k is reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What Was Happening

To explain what happens here:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT to *the entire process group*. That means it doesn't just terminate `tcpdump`, but also terminates `gzip`. (The workarounds you were attempting try to avoid this by moving content into background processes, and thus out of the same process group).
- stdout is line-buffered by default only when output is to a TTY; when output is to a FIFO, it's block-buffered, allowing greater efficiency by writing data from the left-hand process only when a sufficiently larger chunk is available. In *many* situations, you could thus just use `stdbuf -oL` or similar to disable this. However...
- `gzip` *by its nature* cannot operate completely unbuffered. This is because block-based compression algorithms need to collect data into, well, *blocks*; analyze that content in bulk; &c.

So, if `gzip` and `tcpdump` are terminated at the same time, that means there's no assurance that `tcpdump` will actually be able to flush its output buffer, *and then have `gzip` read, compress and write that flushed data*, before `gzip` itself exits from the signal it received at the same time.

---

### Fixing The Problem

Note that the code snippets under headers containing the word "Interactive" are intended for *interactive use*.

---

#### A Reliable Interactive Workaround (For Bash)

As a surefire solution, move the `gzip` completely out-of-band, so it isn't prone to being sent a SIGINT when you press ctrl+c on the `tcpdump` command:

```
exec 3> >(gzip -c >test.gz)  # Make FD 3 point to gzip
tcpdump -l -i eth0 >&3       # run tcpdump **AS A SEPARATE COMMAND** writing to that fd
exec 3>&-                    # later, after you cancelled tcpdump, close the FD.
```

---

#### A Reliable Interactive Workaround (For Any POSIX Shell)

Same thing, but slightly longer and not relying on process substitution:

```
mkfifo test.fifo                            # create a named FIFO
gzip -c <test.fifo >test.gz & gzip_pid="$!" # start gzip, reading from that named FIFO
tcpdump -l -i eth0 >test.fifo               # start tcpdump, writing to that named FIFO
rm test.fifo                                # delete the FIFO when done
wait "$gzip_pid"                            # ...and wait for gzip to exit
```

Note that the `wait` will have the exit status of the gzip process, so you can determine whether it encountered an error.

---

#### A Reliable Scripted Workaround (For Any POSIX Shell)

If we're running a script, then it's appropriate to set up a signal handler so we can handle SIGINT (by killing *only* tcpdump) explicitly:

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$#" -gt 0 ] || {
  echo "Usage: ${0##*/} file.tcpdump.gz [tcpdump-args]" >&2
  echo "  Example: ${0##*/} foo.tcpdump.gz -l -i eth0" >&2
  exit 1
}
outfile=$1; shift
fifo=test-$$.fifo # for real code, put this in a unique temporary directory

trap '[ -n "$tcpdump_pid" ] && kill "$tcpdump_pid"' INT
trap 'rm -f -- "$fifo"' EXIT

rm -f -- "$fifo"; mkfifo "$fifo" || exit
gzip -c >"$outfile" <"$fifo" & gzip_pid=$!

# avoid trying to run tcpdump if gzip obviously failed to start
{ [ -n "$gzip_pid" ] && [ "$gzip_pid" -gt 0 ] && kill -0 "$gzip_pid"; } || exit 1

tcpdump "$@" >"$fifo" & tcpdump_pid=$!

# return exit status of tcpdump if it fails, or gzip if tcpdump succeeds
wait "$tcpdump_pid" || wait "$gzip_pid"
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Charles Duffy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50489473/494725) answer (a big thanks to him!):

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT to *the entire process group*. That means it doesn't just terminate `tcpdump`, but also terminates `gzip`. (The workarounds you were attempting try to avoid this by moving content into background processes, and thus out of the same process group).

Since he's right that `gzip` writes the output file only when a full `32k block` is compressed, I've started the 'obvious solution' in one terminal...

```
$ tcpdump -l -i eth0 | gzip -c > test.gz
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
1926 packets captured
1938 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
$
```

and killed the tcpdump from a second terminal:

```
$ killall -INT tcpdump
$
```

Starting the 'obvious solution' in background `tcpdump -l -i eth0 | gzip -c > test.gz &` would allow to kill the tcpdump from the same terminal.