# How to capture stderr and stdout AND timing info with tee including SIGINT?

Tags: bash, time, pipe, io-redirection, tee

Suppose I have a program `foo` which prints to both stderr and stdout. I want to be able to time it and `tee` the output to a log file.

## Program Description

I can call `foo` as follows:

```
user$ time ./foo
```

This gives (for example) output on two streams:

*stdout:*

```
stdout says hi
```

*stderr:*

```
stderr says hi
```

## Combining stderr and stdout

I can combine them easily enough to standard output using BASH I/O redirection:

```
user$ ./foo 2>&1
```

This gives the following output:

*stdout:*

```
stdout says hi
stderr says hi
```

*stderr:*  (empty!)

## Using `tee`

I can capture the combined output of the program using `tee`:

```
user$ ./foo 2>&1 | tee log.txt
```

*stdout:*

```
stdout says hi
stderr says hi
```

*stderr:*  (empty!)

*log.txt:*

```
stdout says hi
stderr says hi
```

## Capturing Timing using `time`

I can time the execution of my program using BASH's builtin `time` command *while* combining stdout and stderr:

```
user$ time ./foo 2>&1
```

*stdout:*

```
stdout says hi
stderr says hi
```

*stderr:*:

```
real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.004s
```

I can capture the output of the `time` command as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408981/how-can-i-redirect-the-output-of-the-time-command) and redirect it to a file:

```
user$ ( time ./foo ) > log.txt
```

*stdout:*  (empty!)

*stderr:*

```
stderr says hi

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.004s
```

*log.txt:*
    stdout says hi

## Combining I/O, Capturing `time`'s output, AND piping to `tee`

How can this be done? I'm imagining something like the following:

```
( time ./foo 2&>1 ) | tee log.txt
```

*stdout:*  (empty!)

```
stdout says hi
stderr says hi

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.004s
```

*stderr:*  (empty!)

*log.txt:*

```
stdout says hi
stderr says hi

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.004s
```

Doing the following works, except when I Ctrl-C (SIGINT) out of the program prematurely.

```
( time ./foo ) 2&>1 | tee log.txt
```

How can I get it to work when I Ctrl-C as well?

Comment: Your link suggests using `(time ls) &> file`, which would have worked in your case, too. So why did you leave out the `&`? (That is `(time ...) |& tee ...`)

Comment: @rici: Good suggestion. That syntax didn't work for me when using `GNU bash version 3.2.57(1)-release` (remote computer I can't update BASH on), though it *does* appear to work for `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release` (I can and have updated BASH). I'll see if my sysadmins can update BASH on the remote machine, but I'm still interested in a solution.

Comment: Part of what's tricky with piping to `tee`, by the way, is that ctrl+c sends a SIGINT to the whole process group -- so it shuts down `tee` at the same time as it shuts down the subshell running `time`, meaning you can't guarantee (ie. it's dependent on the outcome of a race) whether `tee` is actually able to flush that shell's output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myfunc() { echo stdout; echo stderr >&2; sleep 3; }
{ time myfunc; } > >(tee log.txt) 2>&1
```

...emits content *including* `time` metadata to `log.txt`, even when cancelled with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

See [Write tcpdump output to compressed / gziped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489159/write-tcpdump-output-to-compressed-gziped-file/50489473) for a more-in-depth discussion of the same problem, including an answer intended for scripts as opposed to interactive interpreters.

---

For the program `foo` in your example, you could do the following:

```
{ time ./foo; } > >(tee log.txt) 2>&1
```

Comment: @jvriesem, ...re: edit, I'd expect you could just `time ./foo`, vs needing the function (which was added just for testability purposes) and to `time myfunc`; is that not the case?

Comment: Sure enough! `{ time myfunc; } > >(tee log.txt) 2>&1` seems sufficient. Thank you! (Edited the answer.)